# How can I cd using a variable in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit # Exit on error

# Enable script to run from anywhere
root="$(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})"

cd "$($root)"

source ./scripts/main
cd "$($root)"

pwd

source ./scripts/test

cd "$($root)/applicant"

yarn build
```

But I get this error:

> ./build.sh: line 8: .: filename argument required

How can I get a variable of the current directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it simply:

```
cd $variable_with_path
```

In your example you should replace *"$($root)"* by *$root*

---

To get variable with current directory:

```
path=`pwd`
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `pwd`  for current directory.

```
-61T9:~ pwd
/Users/test
-61T9:~ s=`pwd`
-61T9:~ echo $s
/Users/test
```